# How to find repeated patterns of numbers in the rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, pattern-matching, permutation

Say that I have a matrix with `N` rows (`N` is known) containing the same numbers but in different order in each row. The numbers are the same for each row, 1-9, and there are no duplicates of a number in the same row. Each row will have just a different order of the same numbers. I'd like to detect patterns of numbers in the different rows. By "pattern" I mean any repeated combination of two or more numbers.

For example if I have a matrix as below:

```
1   2   3   8   9   7   4   5   6
1   3   2   7   8   9   4   5   6
1   2   3   5   6   7   4   9   8
1   2   3   7   8   6   4   5   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   7   8   9   4   5   6
1   3   2   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

one pattern is the set 1-2-3 (appears 5 times, in rows 1,3,4,5,6),
another pattern is the set 4-5-6 (appears 5 times, in the rows 1,2,5,6,7).

Is there anything for this in MATLAB?

I thought about starting with a command that generates all the possible combinations for the numbers 1-9 with 2-9 digits. For each combination generated, I'll scan all the matrix and count how many times appears and in which rows. And then the combinations occurring the most will be printed out. Does it sound feasible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. One of the most important aspects of asking questions here is **do your research and show it**. Thus, please [edit] the question to show what you already found out about this problem, and preferably add your code, this is called a [mcve]. List where you are stuck, whether it errors, gives incorrect results etc.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "sequence"? Is `1   2   3   8   9   7   4   5   6` a sequence? `1 2`? `5`?

Comment: As sequence I take a series of two or more numbers, a combination. I've edited my question so it's not confusing with the term "sequence".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a vector placed horizontally or vertically in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47488391/find-a-vector-placed-horizontally-or-vertically-in-a-matrix)

Comment: Why is this question still on hold as unclear? Following the edit the question seems clear enough.

Comment: I vote to re-open the question which is for me clear enough to be answered. I also find the question interesting.

Comment: Three questions: 1) will the matrix always be square? 2) what are the bounds of `N`? (these should be well-defined, because a solution that is good for a 9x9 matrix might not scale too well) 3) In your example you discussed a combination like 1-2-3, but this contains also 1-2 and 2-3.. So do you want a count of all possible combinations of lengths 2 to N, or only combinations that appear more than X times, or only combinations that are not a part of a longer sequence?

Comment: @Dev-iL 1,2) the matrix will be 9xN with N >20, 3) I'm looking for the longest combination (if it's possible), so in the case of the triplet 1-2-3, I want only the triplet and not the doubles 1-2, 2-3. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: @Dev-iL Thank you very much for this, it's really helpful and I appreciate the time for developing this code. The issue is that the pattern might also be in any order. So for example for the numbers 4-5-6, a pattern might be 5-4-6 or 6-5-4.

Comment: @Dimitrios this is something you should definitely mention in advance. Fortunately, it's quite simple to adapt my solution to do both. I'll update it soon.

Comment: @Dev-iL Sorry for this, I'm quite new to matlab so I couldn't think that this wouldn't be clear from my description. Many thanks again for your interest and time.

Comment: @Dev-iL I have question on the code. Why each time I run it , it returns a different result? Also the chart in the doesn't look correct. For example the combination 1   3   2   7   8   9   4   5 doesn't appear 3 times in the matrix.

Comment: The reason the output is random is because you probably call it with the `isRandomM` input set to `true`. Note that if the order is not important, and you only want the longest combination, it will always be the trivial solution - `[1 ... N]`. Thanks for the notice regarding the wrong histogram, I'll take a look at why this happens.

Comment: No, you said that the number of rows is always 9. Look at the code, I've added comments. It's very easy to make the number of rows (`R`) an input instead of a constant. In fact, it was originally an input in my code until you said the amount of rows is fixed.

Comment: No, the number of rows is N known but the number of columns is 9 which is fixed because you have combinations with 9 digits from 1 to 9. However as the matrix is given as input in the function this doesn't make any difference, does it?

Comment: @DimitriosAnagnostakis you got your very very good answer. Please be respectful and do try to understand it.

Comment: @Ander Biguri I really appreciate the effort Dev-iL made for this, Apologies if I seemed to be rude...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer below relies on several assumptions (since I started writing it before the OP's latest clarification comment):

- **Scalability**: this was designed for arrays of about the same size as in the question. It should not be assumed that this is a suitable solution for any `N`.
- **Sub-sequences**: I'm assuming that all sequences of length 2 up to `N` are desired, even if they appear inside a longer sequence.
- **Location**: we do not care *where* the sequences appear, just *how often* they do. If the position is required, you can apply the solution shown in [the Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47488391/3372061) referenced [by rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521534/how-to-find-repeated-patterns-of-numbers-in-the-rows-of-a-matrix#comment90013563_51521534).
- **Repeating rows**: allowed.
- **Output**: by default, only combinations that appear **more than** twice.

The idea of the solution is as follows:

1. Initialize an empty cell array that would hold sequences.
2. Take a row from the matrix.
3. Cut it up into all combinations of lengths `2` to `N`. Store all combinations in the cell vector.
4. If there are any more unprocessed rows remaining, go to 2; otherwise aggregate and display results.

Furthermore we use the [GetMD5](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25921) tool to compare inhomogenous data (in this case, vectors of different length).

```
function varargout = q51521534(isRandomM, N, ignoreOrder, minAppear)
%% Handling inputs:
if nargin < 1
  % Should we generate a random matrix, or use a hardcoded default?
  isRandomM = false;
end
if isRandomM && nargin < 2
  % Number of columns.
  N = 30;
end
if nargin < 3
  % When this flag is true, [1 2 3] is considered the same as [3 1 2] etc.
  ignoreOrder = true;
end
if nargin < 4
  % The minimal frequancy needed to be plotted in the histogram.
  minAppear = 4;
end
%% Definitions:
R = 9;
MIN_LEN = 2;
%% Setup:
if isRandomM
  M = zeros(R,N);
  for ind1 = 1:R
    M(ind1,:) = randperm(N,N);
  end
else % the example from the question:
  M = uint8([ 
      1   2   3   8   9   7   4   5   6
      1   3   2   7   8   9   4   5   6
      1   2   3   5   6   7   4   9   8
      1   2   3   7   8   6   4   5   9
      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
      1   2   3   7   8   9   4   5   6
      1   3   2   4   5   6   7   8   9]);
  [R,N] = size(M);
end
%% Populate the "row-chopping" indices:
allIdx = cell(N-MIN_LEN+1,1);
for ind1 = MIN_LEN:N
  allIdx{ind1-1} = (1:ind1) + (0:N-ind1).';
end
%% Extract sequences from every row according to the indices:
S = cell((N-1)*R,1);
if ignoreOrder
  for ind1 = 1:R
    idx = (1:N-1) + (N-1)*(ind1-1);
    S(idx) = cellfun(@(x){sort(reshape(M(ind1,x.'), size(x,2),[]).',2)}, allIdx);
  end  
else
  for ind1 = 1:R
    idx = (1:N-1) + (N-1)*(ind1-1);
    S(idx) = cellfun(@(x){reshape(M(ind1,x.'), size(x,2),[]).'}, allIdx);
  end
end
S = cellfun(@(x)num2cell(x,2), S, 'UniformOutput', false); S = vertcat(S{:});
% S now contains all sequences **appearing in the array**.
%% Analyze the output:
md5 = string(cellfun(@GetMD5, S, 'UniformOutput', false));
[~,ia,ic] = unique(md5, 'stable'); uS = S(ia);
N = histcounts(ic,'BinMethod','integers');
%% Show chart:
f = find(N >= minAppear); % ignore combinations that appear less than a threshold
figure(); hB = bar(N(f)); hB.Parent.XTickLabelRotation = 45;
hB.Parent.XTickLabel = string(cellfun(@mat2str, uS(f), 'UniformOutput', false));
%% Assign outputs:
if nargout > 0
  varargout{1} = M;
  varargout{2} = S;
  varargout{3} = ic;
end
```

For the array in the question (`q51521534(false,[],false,3)`), this results in:

[image: Histogram of combinations]

To get a sense of how long it takes to run:

```
>> tic; q51521534(true,30,false); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.075122 seconds.

>> tic; q51521534(true,100,false); toc;
Elapsed time is 0.426620 seconds.

>> tic; q51521534(true,200,false); toc;
Elapsed time is 9.765767 seconds.
```